# lspci detects no VGA

Tags: graphics, pci, lspci

I have booted my ubuntu with the options quiet splash erased and acpi=off

Previously I checked in the BIOS that my graphic card is detected (it was not enabled)

Now in ubuntu I do

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

and nothing appears.

What is happening, why and how can I correct this?

The monitor is connected to the Nvidia video card

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

also gives nothing

EDIT:

```
$lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers (rev 04)
00:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers (rev 04)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS (rev 04)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOAPIC (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:08.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation X299 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` without any `grep`.

Comment: What model of video card does your system contain? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubunt 20.04.1 LTS   Nvidia GTX 1080Ti GP102

Comment: @Pilot6 I added that